# If $\int f_n dx \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, then $\int f_n^2 dx \to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given that $f_n\in L^2$, where $L^2$ a metric space on real line with respect to Lebesgue measure.

If $\int f_n dx \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, then  $\int f_n^2 dx \to 0$, May I ask if this statement is correct?

Part of my proof relies on that, but I'm not sure if this is true. Since $\int f_n dx \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\ge N$, we have $|\int f_n dx|<\epsilon$. Recall the definition of Lebesgue integral, it is $\sup\{I_E(s): s \text{ is simple, measurable, $0\le s\le f_n$}\}$, where $I_E(s) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i m(E\cap E_i)$. And then apply the definition on $\int f_n^2 dx$. Am I on the right track? Honestly I'm not sure where it goes.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct. How about consider $f_n(x) = \sqrt{n}I_{(0, n^{-1})}(x)$? Then $\int f_n(x) dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$, but $\int f_n^2(x) dx \equiv 1 \not\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you for providing this counter example. If I add the assumption that $f$ is a continuous function on the real line, would the statement be true?

Comment: @YIRANJIA No, it's still not. I believe you could construct a similar counterexample by applying the common "continuous adaption" method to the example I presented above. That is, right now the area under $f_n$ is a rectangle. But you could modify it to a trapezoid by slanting the vertical edges a little bit so that $f_n$ becomes continuous everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

For an example with $f_n$'s continuous take $f_n(x)=0$ for $x \leq 0$ and $x \geq \frac   2n$, $f_n(x)=\sqrt n$ for $0 \leq x \leq \frac  1n$ and $f_n(x)=n^{3/2} (\frac  2 n -x)$ for $\frac  1n \leq x \leq \frac  2 n$.